# BSC testnet seems to be not up to date at truffle

Tags: truffle, testnets, truffle-migration, bsc

it looks like my truffle setup is far behind the actual testnet, resulting that I cant deploy anything (getting timeout)

##### Code to reproduce

truffle-config.js

```
    bsctestnet: {
    provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545`),
    network_id: 97,
    confirmations: 10,
    timeoutBlocks: 200,
    skipDryRun: true
    },
```

> npx truffle console --network bsctestnet
> truffle(bsctestnet)> web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
> 11448934
> truffle(bsctestnet)>

The actual block number is: [11556148](https://testnet.bscscan.com/block/11556148)

Also when I repeat the command its stay the old (11448934). So looks like truffle don't get synced at all.

##### Environment

Truffle v5.3.12 (core: 5.3.12)
Solidity - 0.8.6 (solc-js)
Node v14.15.1
Web3.js v1.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Okay found the problem:

Used another endpoint...
https://data-seed-prebsc-2-s1.binance.org:8545/